# youcompleteme doesn't auto-complete c++ functions

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I installed plugin youcomplete ,but it doesn't work well.
When i type `ve`,i want it prompt me `vector`,but it did nothing.
When i type `vector<int> vec;vec.`,after i type `.`,i wanti it prompt the functions of vector,but i did nothing.
here is my .vimrc file

```
let g:ycm_warning_symbol = '>*'
let g:ycm_error_symbol = '>>'
let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf = 0
let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf='~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py'
```